# Error when upgrade angular 2.0.0-beta.13 to 2.0.0 rc1

Tags: angular

I have a project run Angular 2.0.0-beta.13, i had upgrade to Angular 2.0.0 rc1.
But, i have some errors

[image: error image]

This is my source:

- package.json
  ...

  "dependencies": {
  "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
  "angular2-notifications": "0.1.47",
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
  "async": "^1.5.2",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
  "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
  "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
  "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
  "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
  "jquery": "^2.2.1",
  "jsforce": "^1.6.0",
  "lodash": "^4.5.1",
  "ng2-bootstrap": "1.0.10",
  "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.1.7",
  "ng2-material": "^0.2.7",
  "raf.js": "0.0.4"
  }

...

- Here are file config.ts
  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94076278/etc/config.ts

Answer (score 0):

With RC version, the `angular2` NPM module can't be used anymore but the following ones:

```
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1"
```

Moreover Angular2 RC versions don't provide (yet) bundled files like `angular2.dev.js` or `http.dev.js` files. There is no more `angular2-polyfill` and you need to configure ZoneJS and Reflect-metadata explictly instead.

You need to configure it within your SYstemJS configuration. See this page for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Regarding your problem, I think that you should remove this line from your `package.json` file:

```
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
```

Check that angular2-notifications is compliant with RC versions of Angular2.

Finally update your config.ts file not to use files from beta versions. Here is a sample:

```
{ src: 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js', inject: 'shims', dest: JS_DEST },
(...)
{ src: 'angular2/bundles/angular2.js', inject: 'libs', dest: JS_DEST },
{ src: 'angular2/bundles/router.js', inject: 'libs', dest: JS_DEST },
{ src: 'angular2/bundles/http.js', inject: 'libs', dest: JS_DEST },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its good idea to have both - beta and rc - as dependency. Also with rc release, there are many breaking changes, especially because of the modularized package structure. Also its difficult to say what exactly is causing the error as you have not posted the source of `accounts`as shown in console. I recently upgraded my angular 2 app (which I'm using to explore Angular 2) to RC release and I'd to perform couple of steps which I've documented here. Have a look at it and see if its of any help. https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2016/05/upgrading-angular-2-from-beta-to-rc.html